# what is the solution for knowing my server name?

Tags: sqlcmd

what is the solution for knowing my server name?
when I typed sqlcmd -L for my server name in command prompt it doesn't show my server name . What should I do to resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017#command-line-options). You could be looking for the `-H` option

> -H workstation_name A workstation name. This option sets the sqlcmd scripting variable SQLCMDWORKSTATION. The workstation name is listed
>   in the hostname column of the sys.sysprocesses catalog view and can be
>   returned using the stored procedure sp_who. If this option is not
>   specified, the default is the current computer name. This name can be
>   used to identify different sqlcmd sessions.

Comment: That doesn't work.It shows "couldn't open a connection to sql server".